# Future that cannot fail in Scala

Tags: scala, future

Is there the concept of a `Future` that cannot fail in Scala?

I'm transforming a `Future[Result]`, which may fail—therefore I handle both a `Failure` and a `Success`—into a `Future[Option[String]]`, carrying an optional error message derived from the failure or success states. So far, so good.

Thing is now, I would like to formally (i.e., with the help of the type system) remember that this future will always hold a `Success` and that I won't need to handle the failure case in the future.

Is there a smart way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need this? 
edit: Are you just ignoring some:Result to return optional error message: String?

Comment: Why not `Future[Try[T]]`?

Comment: @cchantep I don't see the point with that: I would have to handle both the future's failure, and the fact that the future, even if itself is a success, may hold a `Failure` value. Quite the opposite of what I want.

Comment: @HüseyinZengin I “need” this because I want the compiler to tell me, if I try to handle a failure on my transformed future that cannot fail, “hey man, no need to do this, this future cannot be in a failure state”.

Comment: With `Try`, the `Future` won't handle failure, just the async. Aside from that, `.recover` can be used.

Comment: @cchantep I don't get your point; could you write a simple example as an answer?

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet Oh I see, what about creating a new class say "AlwaysSuccess" extends Future, override onFailure, onComplete, onSuccess etc and using macro to throw a compile time error?

Comment: @HüseyinZengin Cool, I didn't know I could override methods with macro methods to produce errors. Any pointers on examples of that?

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet What if out of memory exception happens during your `Future`? Do you still consider it as a success?

Comment: @Archeg Such errors (and others, see `scala.util.control.NonFatal` for a list of fatal errors) are not captured into a `Failure` value, but propagated anyway.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet I was just talking about extending a class/trait and overriding methods and giving errors but it turns out it is not possible or at least easy with `Future`, all `Future` impl. is private and extending and overriding them is not seems possible

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet Ah, yes, you are right. But it still does not explain what your `Future` should return if any non-fatal exception happens there. Even if you are sure you do not have those - I don't think you can make compiler be sure of that as well

Comment: I was playing a bit with the idea proposed by @Jean-PhilippePelle, I extended Future using delegation. http://scalafiddle.net/console/3ce0331cbd983f1689e1eea65561cac. I works, but of course, every time you do a transformation you get back a normal future.

Comment: But using catching all [Throwable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html)'s `Error`'s too (rather than just `Exception`'s is bad practice, as I understand. [Error](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html)'s docs explain: `An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems that a reasonable application should not try to catch`.

Comment: @KevinMeredith What's your point? No one is catching those.

Comment: That's what `Future { ... } .recover { case _ => ... }` will do, per its [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.concurrent.Future). I'm referring to Dima's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36085821/409976) though.

Comment: @KevinMeredith Futures don't catch and failed Futures can't hold fatal errors, so `recover { case _ => ??? }` is equivalent to `recover { case NonFatal(_) => ??? }`: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html#exceptions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't this what type-tagging is for?

```
scala> type Tagged[U] = { type Tag = U }
defined type alias Tagged

scala> type @@[T, U] = T with Tagged[U]
defined type alias $at$at

scala> trait OK ; trait Uncertain
defined trait OK
defined trait Uncertain

scala> type Sure[A] = Future[A] @@ OK
defined type alias Sure

scala> type Unsure[A] = Future[A] @@ Uncertain
defined type alias Unsure

scala> val f = Future.successful(42).asInstanceOf[Sure[Int]]
f: Sure[Int] = Future(Success(42))
```

then

```
scala> object X { def p(f: Sure[_]) = "sure" ; def p(f: Unsure[_])(implicit d: DummyImplicit) = "unsure" }
defined object X

scala> X.p(f)
res1: String = sure
```

It doesn't remain sure under map, of course.

Comment: That's quite nice indeed. (a) Can I add new methods to such a `Sure[A]` type? (b) Can I get the compiler to somehow tell me "don't call onFailure on `Sure[A]`, dummy"?

Comment: You can do extension methods via type classes as usual. You could make a type class for a custom `onFailing` that would not apply for `Sure` by introducing an ambiguous implicit. Your normal onFailing would just forward to f.onFailure.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose you meant “You can do extension methods via **implicit** classes.”

Comment: "type class" is the generic term, that is implemented as an "implicit class".

Answer (score 6):

You cannot do that "with the help of type system" because there is no way for the type system to guarantee a `Future` will not fail, even if you promise that it won't.

Consider this:

```
 Future { doStuff(); }
   .recover { case _ => "Failed!" } // Now it always succeeds
   .map { _ => Seq.empty[String].head }  // Now it does not.
```

Even if you were going to make any further transformations impossible, once the `Future` has been declared to always succeed, that still does not help, because the exception handler (or whatever you do to convert the original future to the "always succeeding one") could throw.

**Update:** as pointed out in a comment below, the code snippet above is incorrect: the result of `.map` is not the same `Future` as the result of `.recover`. The point stands however. Here is the correct illustration:

```
Future { doStuff }
  .recover { case _ => Seq.empty[String].head }
```

Comment: Isn't `.recover { case _ => "Failed!" }` a bad idea since you're catching `java.lang.Error` too?

Comment: @KevinMeredith Yeah ... it was just an example for the sake of illustration. Do not put it in production :)

Comment: The result of the recover and the result of the map are two different futures, so "it" changes referent. There's nothing inherently wrong with asserting to the compiler, "I know something you don't about the result of recover." Maybe a side-effect checker is run off-line. Moreover you only have to reason about `Nonfatal` exceptions. If it throws InterruptedException, then the future simply doesn't complete. So "success" is predicated on completing.

Comment: I completely disagree with this answer. You can make an expression for every type that fails (`Sys.error(…)`). The type-system does not pretect you from `List().head` in the first place, no matter whether you wrap it into a `Future` or into a `Stream`, where it will also crash once the `Stream` is forced. But still we use types because they're useful.

Comment: `Moreover you only have to reason about Nonfatal exceptions.` Then would you say it's appropriate, @som-snytt, to only include `{ case scala.util.control.NonFatal(_) => ...`?

Comment: @ziggystar "The type-system does not pretect you from List().head in the first place"  you are arguing exactly my point :)

Comment: @som-snytt you are right about the result of `.map` being different, point taken. You are wrong about the rest of it though. Almost _all_ exceptions, are "NonFatal", including `NullPointerException`, `NoSuchElementException`, `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception etc. 
You are confusing a `NonFatal` exception with an "unintentional" one. It is not the same thing. You can assert to the compiler that you do not _intend_ to throw an exception, but that assertion is not at all equivalent to the guarantee, that an exception (a NonFatal one) will not be thrown.

Comment: I didn't see the at-mention somehow. I think what I meant was: an InterruptedException for example means the future doesn't complete, so it's not meaningful to ask whether to handle failure. Non-completion is not failure. In particular, you'll never see: We ran out of memory but you completed anyway, now what? That is how `NonFatal` is used in the framework, not in the amorphous way you claim I'm using it. Once I've convinced my boss I'm handling it correctly, I can cast. Keep in mind that a guarantee by the compiler is only as good as its correctness, too.

Comment: @somsnytt let's do way with "my amorphous way", and get concrete. NullPointerException is NonFatal. True or false?